# Which version of assembly does OllyDbg disassemble binary to?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

So I understand that there are many assemblers such as MASM, FASM, NASM, etc.

But which version is the disassembler in OllyDbg and Cheat Engine?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you already know, OllyDBG only supports (afaik) the x86 instruction set. So, what you're seeing will always be 8/16/32-bit instructions.

MASM, FASM and NASM are all based on the Intel syntax (as opposed to AT&T version which is primarily used on Unix by GAS), but are in themselves different (feature-wise).

OllyDBG disassembles to MASM syntax by default. You can change this by going to Options -> Options...

[image]

Wikipedia gives a good example of Intel vs AT&T syntax: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax